# Hibernate and PostgreSQL: Can I configure GenerationType.IDENTITY, where each id column's default value comes from a shared sequence?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

Ok I am not 100% sure if I really want this but currently it seems like a good idea.

I configure my entities like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id = 0;
```

If I let Hibernate generate the table, the result is:

```
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

The bigserial in turn translates into a bigint with a default value of:

```
nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass)
```

Now that's ok but I am currently considering using a single sequence for all tables and would like the default value to be:

```
nextval('my_global_sequence'::regclass)
```

Maybe I could go and manually adjust the default value later, but do you have any ideas how I could tell hibernate to define the table like this automatically? Is there maybe a way to push my own create table sql strategy that would issue code like this for the id column (untested SQL syntax):

```
id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT = nextval('my_global_sequence'::regclass)
```

Note that I would like to stick with the IDENTITY strategy, because I want to avoid any "hi/lo multiplying allocation size cache sequence whatever"-strategies. From time to time I need to insert some manual rows through pgAdmin without risking any id conflict with hibernate. All the other strategies seem like magic to me (= I don't understand them).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out how to do this with hibernate. My current solution is just a plain old JDBC/SQL logic that I execute on every startup. So far I am pretty happy about it.

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword);

String catalog = connection.getCatalog();
String schema = "public";

DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();

ResultSet tablesResultSet = databaseMetaData.getTables(catalog, schema, null, new String[] { "TABLE" });

while(tablesResultSet.next())
{
  String tableName = tablesResultSet.getString("TABLE_NAME");

  LOGGER.info("updating table: '" + tableName + "', setting global sequence");

  // update primary keys to global sequence
  {
    //        LOGGER.info("setting global sequence for '" + tableName + "'.id");

    connection.createStatement().execute("ALTER TABLE \"" + tableName + "\" ALTER COLUMN id TYPE bigint;");
    connection.createStatement().execute("ALTER TABLE \"" + tableName + "\" ALTER COLUMN id SET NOT NULL;");
    connection.createStatement().execute("ALTER TABLE \"" + tableName + "\" ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('my_global_sequence'::regclass)");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use an annotation on your id to determine the sequence generator you wish to use:

Using your code as an example:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_global_sequence")
private long id = 0;
```

With this annotation it is simple to configure specific sequence generators for each entity or group of entities, or even use the same everywhere.

The caveat is that you have to define that annotation for every entity you have

Comment: I tested this and it does not work for me. The id column gets defined as bigserial, which results in a sequence names 'test_id_seq' being created. To me it looks like the GenerationType.IDENTITY takes precedence over any @SequenceGenerator annotations.